# Umlaut not working in Windows

Tags: babel, input-encodings, german, visual-studio-code

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and wanted to setup my Visual Studio Code to work with LaTeX.

At the moment the compiler always throws an error when I am trying to compile a document with umlauts in it.

I am using a Windows computer so every tutorial is suggesting to use the following packages for this task:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I always get the following error message:

```
Output written on <<path of pdf file>> (3 pages, 23589 
bytes).
Transcript written on <<path to log file>>.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'test.pdf'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to <<path to log file>> for details
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
```

I can't even see a broken compiled PDF.

I have tried to use the options `utf8`, `latin1` and `latin9` for `inputenc` but neither of them worked so far.

Am I missing something? Is there something I should else try?

EDIT: Thanks for all your ideas, as requested here is my smallest project that does not work:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Ä Ö Ü ä ö ü ß

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Any online tutorial that recommends using the option `ansinew` with the `inputenc` package is probably grossly out of date. Which input encoding system did you select when you set up the front-end editor?

Comment: Please post a minimum working example of a LaTeX document that generates the issue(s) you're experiencing.

Comment: latex (and visual studio code) default tio UTF-8 so you should be able to delete `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}`

Comment: Try typesetting with `XeLaTeX` instead of `LaTeX`, and use only the `fontspec` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried to delete this package it still doesn't work.

Comment: @HelmutK. Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, you should use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Don't use a build tool like latexmk if you want to debug a problem. Run only pdflatex to get better error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you tried the utf8 option for inputenc - what error message does the following give you?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Ä Ö Ü ä ö ü ß
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey I think this fixes it for me. I am pretty sure I have tried every combination with [utf8] and [ansinew] and others as well. I have never tried without the {fontenc} after deleting this package it started to work! Vielen Dank.